# Generating railroad diagrams with pyparsing 2.4.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

The documentation at https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowToUsePyparsing.html#generating-railroad-diagrams specifies the command `pip install pyparsing[diagrams]`. When `pyparsing 2.4.7` is installed this command does not work returning the message `pyparsing 2.4.7 does not provide the extra 'diagrams'`.
Since this is working for `pyparsing 3.0.0a2` when installed, I am wondering whether the documentation is incorrect or whether something is missing in the `pyparsing 2.4.7` package... or eventually whether I am going mad.
Anyhow is it possible to create railroad diagrams with `pyparsing 2.4.7`?

Comment: No, support for railroad diagrams is new in 3.0.0, and is not available in 2.4.7. If you would like it backported into a potential 2.4.8 release, please open an issue on the pyparsing GitHub (no promises, though).

Comment: Thank you, I think it is be simpler (and less work for you) to install temporarily the version 3.0.0a2 to get the railroad diagram out.